# when i use window.print() the whole style is corrupted, i tried @media screen and @media print, but same result

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

iam creating an invoice, the design is perfect in the browser, but when i try to window.print() the style is corrupted, i tried to include @ media screen, and @ media print, but iam getting the same result.
the invoice form is included in a page that has a sidebar, and a navigation bar, i tried to create the invoice form in a separated page that has only the invoice form but i had the same issue! please help
rgds,

browser image:
[image: screenshot from browser]
print image:

[image: screenshot from printing area]

code:

```
 <html>
<head>

    <style type="text/css">

    body {
    background-color: #000
}

.padding {
    padding: 2rem !important
}

.card {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgba(154, 154, 204, 0.22);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgba(154, 154, 204, 0.22);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px 1px rgba(154, 154, 204, 0.22)
}

.card-header {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6f2
}

h3 {
    font-size: 20px
}

h5 {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 26px;
    color: #3d405c;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    font-family: 'Circular Std Medium'
}

.text-dark {
    color: #3d405c !important
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>




<div class="offset-xl-2 col-xl-8 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 padding" id="alitest">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header p-4">
            <a class="pt-2 d-inline-block" href="" data-abc="true">zigzag.com</a>
            <div class="float-right">
                <h3 class="mb-0">Invoice#: E- <?php echo $invoice_id; ?></h3>
                <h5 class="mb-0">M.O.F: 3003330-601</h5>
                <?php echo date("l");echo "  ";echo date("Y/m/d"); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="row mb-4">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <h5 class="mb-3">From:</h5>
                    <h3 class="text-dark mb-1">ZigZag Toys</h3>
                    <div>Beirut</div>
                    <div>Gallery Semman, Karout Mall, 2nd floor</div>
                    <div>info@zigzaglb.com</div>
                    <div>Phone: 01-542 077 EXT: 2116</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 ">
                    <h5 class="mb-3">To:</h5>
                    <h3 class="text-dark mb-1"><?php echo $cust_fname; echo " ";echo $cust_lname; ?></h3>
                    <div>City: <?php echo $cust_city; ?></div>
                    <div>Address: <?php echo $cust_address; ?></div>
                    <div>E-mail: <?php echo $cust_email; ?></div>
                    <div>Phone: <?php echo $cust_telephone; ?></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-responsive-sm">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="center">ItemCode</th>
                            <th>ItemImg</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th class="right">Price</th>
                            <th class="center">Qty</th>
                            <th class="right">Total</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <?php
                      $get_prod = "select product_code,product_title,product_img1,customer_orders.due_amount,customer_orders.qty
                                  from products,customer_orders
                                  where customer_orders.order_status <> 'Deleted' and products.product_id = customer_orders.product_id and customer_orders.invoice_no = '$invoice_id'";

                      $run_prod = mysqli_query($conn,$get_prod);
                      $sub_total_all_invoice = 0;
                      while($row_prod=mysqli_fetch_array($run_prod)){

                      $prod_code = $row_prod['product_code'];
                      $prod_img = $row_prod['product_img1'];
                      $prod_title = $row_prod['product_title'];
                      $prod_total_price = $row_prod['due_amount'];
                      $prod_qty = $row_prod['qty'];
                      $prod_unit_price = $prod_total_price / $prod_qty;
                      $sub_total_all_invoice = $sub_total_all_invoice + $prod_total_price;
                       ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td class="center invali"><?php echo $prod_code; ?></td>
                            <td class="center"><img class="img-responsive invoiceimg" src="product_images/<?php echo $prod_img; ?>" alt="Product 3a"></td>
                            <td class="left invali"><?php echo $prod_title; ?></td>
                            <td class="right invali"><?php echo $prod_unit_price; ?></td>
                            <td class="center invali"><?php echo $prod_qty; ?></td>
                            <td class="right invali"><?php echo $prod_total_price ?></td>
                        </tr>

                      <?php } ?>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5 ml-auto">
                    <table class="table table-clear">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left">
                                    <strong class="text-dark">Subtotal</strong>
                                    <?php
                                    $get_vat = "select * from vat";
                                    $run_vat = mysqli_query($conn,$get_vat);
                                    $row_vat = mysqli_fetch_array($run_vat);
                                    $vat = $row_vat['vat'];
                                     ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="right">LBP <?php echo $sub_total_all_invoice - ($sub_total_all_invoice * $vat / 100); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left">
                                    <strong class="text-dark">VAT (<?php echo $vat; ?>%)</strong>
                                </td>
                                <td class="right">LBP <?php echo $sub_total_all_invoice * $vat / 100; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left">
                                    <strong class="text-dark">ZigZag Fidelity Points</strong>
                                </td>
                                <?php
                                $get_fid_amount = "select fid_amount from customer_orders where invoice_no = '$invoice_id' group by fid_amount";
                                $set_fid_amount = mysqli_query($conn,$get_fid_amount);
                                $row_fid = mysqli_fetch_array($set_fid_amount);
                                $fid_amount = $row_fid['fid_amount'];

                                 ?>
                                <td class="right">LBP <?php echo $fid_amount; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="left">
                                    <strong class="text-dark">Shipping & Handling</strong>
                                </td>
                                <?php
                                $get_ship_amount = "select ship_amt from ship";
                                $set_ship_amount = mysqli_query($conn,$get_ship_amount);
                                $row_ship = mysqli_fetch_array($set_ship_amount);
                                $ship_amount = $row_ship['ship_amt'];

                                ?>
                                <td class="right">LBP <?php echo $ship_amount; ?></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td class="left">
                                    <strong class="text-dark">Total</strong> </td>
                                <td class="right">
                                    <strong class="text-dark"><?php echo number_format($sub_total_all_invoice - $fid_amount + $ship_amount,1); ?></strong>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer bg-white">
            <p class="mb-0">ZIGZAG TOYS - please contact us for any clarification.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body></html>

<div class="text-center"><!-- text-center Begin -->

 <button type="submit" name="order_confirmation" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="window.print()">

 Print Invoice

</button>


<a href="submit_order.php?invoice_id=<?php echo $invoice_id; ?>"><?php echo '<button type="" name="" class="btn btn-primary">

Complete Order

</button>'; ?></a>


</div><!-- text-center Finish -->





<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your concern. you can try this in style tag:

```
<style media="all">
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, i tried but no joy iam getting the same result

Answer (score 0):

try this once again :

```
<style media="print">
```

Comment: i tried this before, and i did now, getting same result